# primefaces single menuItem in panelmenu

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, menuitem, submenu

I'm trying to implement a menu with JSF 2.2 and Primefaces 5
I added PanelMenu of primefaces. Let's say I have a code snippet like this:

```
    <p:panelMenu>
      <p:menuitem value="Home" url="homee.xhtml" icon="ui-icon-home"/>
      <p:submenu label="User Operations">
        <p:menuitem value="ETC" actionListener="#{menuView.save}" icon="ui-icon-folder-open" />
        <p:menuitem value="New ETC" actionListener="#{menuView.update}"  icon="ui-icon-plusthick" />
      </p:submenu>
    </p:panelMenu>
```

The problem is, when I do this, that single menuItem which doesn't have a surrounding subMenu doesn't show up in the menu.
How can I overcome this?
Thanks.

Comment: normal p:menu doesn't have collapsible categories.

Comment: By the way, this is not my menu. It's sample menu from PF showcase.

Answer (score 2):

you need to put the single menuitem inside a menu tag and outside the panelMenu :

```
<p:menu>
<p:menuitem value="Home" url="homee.xhtml" icon="ui-icon-home"/>
</p:menu>
<p:panelMenu>
<p:submenu label="User Operations">
<p:menuitem value="ETC" actionListener="#{menuView.save}" icon="ui-icon-folder-open" />
<p:menuitem value="New ETC" actionListener="#{menuView.update}"  icon="ui-icon-plusthick" />
</p:submenu>
</p:panelMenu>
```